# insert terms and condition page in iphone application code that is loaded when application is installed

Tags: iphone

i have developed an  iphone  application where i have generated a terms and condition page and  i wand that page to load only at that time of installation and not everytime application is run on iphone. Is there any any way to do this... i am done with this.... should i insert it into the application bundle and show it into settings...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use NSUserDefaults for this. Have a boolean variable that is set when the user agrees to the terms. If it is not set, show the terms upon loading the application. If it is set, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd check a flag of some sort (presence of file, contents of a file, setting in sqlite db, etc) in the app delegate as the app launches and make a conditional decision about what screen loads first.

Comment: Hey thanx... i will try it out.. thanx for getting back to me so early